# Usar o c# para instalar um programa em modo silencioso passando parametros

Tags: c#

Estou tentando criar um programa que instala vários programas de modo silencioso

alguns programas que usam parâmetros simples tipo " /Q" eu consegui e deu certo

mas tem um programa que o parametro é grande e não esto conseguindo resolver

eu nao posso setar um path fixo, pois quero que meu programa funcione em qualquer diretorio ou pasta

o comando é esse: **vcredist_x86.exe /q:a /c:"VCREDI~1.EXE /q:a /c:""msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qn"" "**

via cmd instala perfeitamente, só nao estou conseguindo fazer isso via c#

eu ja tentei varias maneiras mas sem sucesso, um exemplo de uma maneira que eu não funcionou:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    string pathApp = "Visual C++\2005\vcredist_x86.exe";
    FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, pathApp),
    Arguments = " /q:a /c:\"VCREDI~1.EXE / q:a / c:\"\"msiexec / i vcredist.msi / qn\"\" \"",
    WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    UseShellExecute = true
};

using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
    exeProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    exeProcess.WaitForExit(60000);
}
```

o erro que da ele fala que o arquivo nao foi localizado ou ele começa a instalar mostrando na tela sem ser o modo silencioso, como se tivesse ignorado o parametro

**OBS**: tentei varias variações desse codigo, passando o caminho completo do programa, tentei criar um bat e rodar o bat mas tbm nao deu

o que estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido

descobri o problema, o visual studio estava me trolando, toda vez que eu colava o txt ele dava espaço sozinho com isso o argumento ficava incorreto

dai arrumei todos espaço extras que ele colocou e funcionou

exemplo: eu copiei isso " /c:" e ele ficava assim: "/ c:"